# removeaccessrule with powershell on AD OrganizationalUnit not working

Tags: powershell, acl, organizational-unit

I have a delegated permission on an OU that I would like to delete.

```
$SB = "OU=Name of OU,DC=Name,DC=of,DC=Domain"
$ADUC=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit $SB
$OUACL=Get-ACL AD:\$ADN
```

I can get the ACL-Entry I would like to delete with following script:

```
foreach ($access in $OUACL.access){
    foreach ($Value in $access.ObjectType){
        if ($Value -like "bf967a0a-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2"){
            foreach ($Inherit in $Access.IsInherited){
                if ($Inherit -like "False"){
                    $Removeme = $Access
                    #$OUACL.RemoveAccessRule($access) | Out-null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the Variable is correctly filled with the Entry I am looking to remove:

```
ActiveDirectoryRights : ExtendedRight
InheritanceType       : Descendents
ObjectType            : bf967a0a-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
InheritedObjectType   : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ObjectFlags           : ObjectAceTypePresent
AccessControlType     : Allow
IdentityReference     : DOMAIN\GroupName
IsInherited           : False
InheritanceFlags      : ContainerInherit
PropagationFlags      : InheritOnly
```

But If I use $OUACL.RemoveAccessRule($access) I get the return code "False" and the Entry is still within the ACL.

what am I missing?

I tried to remove the Accessrule from ACS and then save it. (the set-acl part is missing, because removefromAccessRule is not working)

Comment: You should never remove an iterator inside a foreach loop.  In your case you are removing $acess.  When you have an array 1,2,3,4 and remove 2 the item 3 then becomes 3.  The way of solving is to go from end of array to beginning or array using code like this : for($i = $OUACL.access.Length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--){ $access = $OUACL.access[$i]}

Comment: the 2 inner loops are not needed, `foreach ($Value in $access.ObjectType){` and `foreach ($Inherit in $Access.IsInherited){` you simply need an `if` condition inside the outer loop that states: `if ($access.ObjectType -eq "bf967a0a-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2" -and -not $Access.IsInherited){` then -> `$OUACL.RemoveAccessRule(...)`

Comment: permission issue? try the operation in a test OU or with a highly privileged account